# Word wrap to long text and displayed in a fixed table in SSRS invoice report

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, reporting-services

I was trying to create invoice reports in SSRS. I am thinking to wrap the long data to fit into my column of SSRS. At the same time I still want to preserve the fixed table layout. And I have to add blank/empty rows if there is no enough data to maintain table layout. 
What I have right now is that I could have sql stored procedure to give empty rows by using loop and temp tale. Everything is doing fine until the description is a bit more longer text. In this case, it was needed to go down to next line/row so that it can be seen fully. But the problem is if it does so, I will have my calculation wrong and cannot maintain the table layout as I have done in previous way. There is an easy way, just to give the high column height for every row- which the result is not favourable. Kindly give me some workaround or solutions or insight, whatsoever. Very much appreciated!
The initial idea was adapted from https://www.intertech.com/Blog/use-sql-server-reporting-services-to-generate-an-invoice-document/ 
This is what I am getting if I set Can Grow Properties True.Here, we are getting inconsistent table layout.
[image]
This is what I am getting if I set Can Grow Properties False. And here, table layout is acceptable but the text are cut off. 
[image]

```
> SET ANSI_NULLS OFF GO SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF GO CREATE PROCEDURE
> [dbo].[uspInvoice] (  @InLinesPerPage int ---determine how many rows
> to display per page ) AS DECLARE @TotalRows int DECLARE @Remainder int
> DECLARE @NumPages int DECLARE @NextPageRows int set @TotalRows= 0
> SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY InvProduct)as InvoiceRow,
>                                            CoID,
>                                            InvNo,
>                                            InvProduct,
>                                            InvDesc,
>                                            InvQuantity,
>                                            InvUnitPrice,
>                                            InvAmt
> 
> into #tempInvoice FROM Invoice_Products1
> 
> 
> 
> SET @TotalRows= @@ROWCOUNT IF @TotalRows=0    BEGIN       WHILE @TotalRows <
> @InLinesPerPage -- Add Blank Rows will generate blank invoice.
>           BEGIN
>               SET @TotalRows= @TotalRows+1
>               INSERT  #tempInvoice
>                (InvoiceRow,
>                CoID,
>                InvNo,
>                InvProduct,
>                InvDesc,
>                InvQuantity,
>                InvUnitPrice,
>                InvAmt
>                )
>                VALUES 
>                (@TotalRows
>                ,''
>                ,0
>                ,''
>                ,''
>                ,''
> 
>                ,null
>                ,null
>                )          END     END ELSE    BEGIN       SET @Remainder =  @TotalRows%@InLinesPerPage -- get remainder       IF @Remainder !=0 
>       BEGIN           -- Get the current page increase by 1 becasue we have a
> remainder.            SET @NumPages = @TotalRows/@InLinesPerPage  +1              SET
> @NextPageRows = @NumPages * @InLinesPerPage           WHILE @TotalRows <
> @NextPageRows -- Add Blank Rows           BEGIN
>               SET @TotalRows= @TotalRows+1
>               INSERT  #tempInvoice
>               (InvoiceRow,
>                CoID,
>                InvNo,
>                InvProduct,
>                InvDesc,
>                InvQuantity,
>                InvUnitPrice,
>                InvAmt
>               )
>               VALUES 
>               (@TotalRows
>               ,''
>               ,0
>               ,''
>               ,''
>               ,''
>               ,null
>               ,null
>               )           END         END     END SELECT * from #tempInvoice order by InvoiceRow asc return
```

Comment: can't read the image.

Comment: @maSTArHiAn, can view the image now?

Comment: are you to attach the page where the description is overlapping thanks

Comment: Can you wrap the field in a text field?

Comment: I haven't tried out word wrapping in my select query yet. But what I think is if I did word wrap in my select . How about the calculation of the lines in the rest of my sql stored procedure? It is going to be haywired?

Comment: Try it for a start. Im pretty sure as long as it within the boundary of the section it should not break your row.

Comment: Afraid that I am unlikely to maintain the table layout.

Comment: You could look at Graphics.MeasureString . This can measure the length of the string based on the font size and render device. You could find out the length of the string that just fills a single line (let's say 100 units) and it your string length is say 250units you know that will need 3 lines so you can calculate how many more rows to show. Check here for details.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb(v=vs.110).aspx

you could write clr function on SQL Server and do the calculation there or do it in code in your report.

Comment: @AlanSchofield . Very interesting, thank you. I will look more into creating CLR and integrating into the project. In fact I have never tried out CLR before.

Comment: Good Luck! It's not a tricky process if you take your time to set everything up, it just seems a bit "black-box" sometimes, when I first added some CLR functions I was convinced I must have missed something in the setup process but it just worked...